# put a value Inside name in input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I put a value(like: 5 or Etc.) Inside the `INPUT => NAME` on the `checkbox(...name="checkbox[HERE][]"...)` after click on button by jQuery?

Html:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[/*HERE*/][]">
```

Please give me an example in http://jsfiddle.net/ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/PNL6h/1/)**

use `.prop` because node name is a property. http://api.jquery.com/prop/

```
$('input:button').click(function(){
    $('input:checkbox').prop('name','checkbox['+10+'][]');
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the `attr()` method on the element.

```
$('input').attr('name','checkbox['+value+'][]');
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only have one checkbox on the page:

```
$('some button selector').click(function(){
  $('input[type=checkbox]').attr('name', 'some value');
});
```